# what is the relation between the a[i-1] of code actually mean can some one explain?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, search, data-structures

*the question was to rearrange an array such that even positioned are greater than odd positioned(1 indexing),
what is this **arr[i-1]** term actually means here a index or a value less than arr[i]

such as
input : 1, 3, 2, 2, 5
output: 1 3 2 5 2

```
for i in range (1,n):
    if arr[i]%2==0:           
        if arr[i]>=arr[i-1]: 
            arr[i-1], arr[i]=arr[i],arr[i-1]
    else:
        if (arr[i] < arr[i - 1]):
            arr[i - 1], arr[i] = arr[i] , arr[i - 1]
```

Comment: if `i = 2` and `arr[i]` is the value at index 2  then `arr[i-1]` is the value at index `i-1`.  `arr[2-1]` is `arr[1]`

Answer (score 0):

`for i in range (1,n):` starts at the second item (index 1) and so `arr[i-1]` is the item immediately before the `i`:th item (zero-based) in `arr`.

The `if` condition is true when `i` is an even number, and the code swaps the item with the one before it if they are in the wrong order.

Similarly, the `else` condition swaps when we are at an odd index and the items are in the wrong order.

The odd formatting obscures the fact that the swapping code is identical in both cases. You could refactor the code to check all the conditions in one go;

```
    if (arr[i]%2==0 and arr[i]>=arr[i-1]) \
            or (arr[i]%2!=0 and arr[i] < arr[i - 1]):
        arr[i - 1], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[i - 1]
```